# Firebase Android app crash when retrieving data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am successfully save data to firebase through my app but i am  face problem to retrieve firebase database data when app start with blank and immediately crash whiteout any log errors.
I search lot but no use and also i changed firebase rules public but no use  here is my code please help me
here is MainActivity

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.30.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

```java
package com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp.classes.Users;

public class Mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebase;
    private DatabaseReference dataReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dataReference = firebase.getReference().child("Users");



        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.story_adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, BlogViewHolder>(
                Userstories.class,
                R.layout.single_post_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                dataReference

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setNameText(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setProfession(model.getprofession());
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View view;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
        }

        public  void setNameText(String title){
            TextView Title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
            Title.setText(title);
        }
        public void setProfession(String Story){
            TextView story = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_story);
            story.setText(Story);
        }

    }

}
```

Logcat

```
02-02 10:01:15.297 10570-10570/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11020
02-02 10:01:15.297 10570-10570/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
02-02 10:01:15.357 10570-10570/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Collection enabled
02-02 10:01:15.357 10570-10570/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: App package, google app id: com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp, 1:462629035094:android:dfe6370866bf9591
02-02 10:01:15.357 10570-10570/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                    adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp
02-02 10:01:15.357 10570-10570/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
02-02 10:01:15.377 10570-10570/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
02-02 10:01:15.397 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Using measurement service
02-02 10:01:15.397 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
02-02 10:01:15.397 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Using measurement service
02-02 10:01:15.397 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
02-02 10:01:15.477 10570-10570/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
02-02 10:01:15.738 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Using measurement service
02-02 10:01:15.738 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
02-02 10:01:15.738 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 10022170
02-02 10:01:15.738 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
02-02 10:01:15.748 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignUpActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-1409030738035503793}]
02-02 10:01:15.818 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Using measurement service
02-02 10:01:15.818 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
02-02 10:01:15.878 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp D/FA: Connected to remote service
02-02 10:01:15.878 10570-10589/com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
02-02 10:01:15.998 32122-10608/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignUpActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-1409030738035503793}]
02-02 10:01:16.008 32122-10608/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: screen_view(_vs), 60
02-02 10:01:16.008 32122-10608/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.jogiprasadpakki.firebaseapp', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignUpActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-1409030738035503793}]}
02-02 10:01:16.018 32122-10608/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 1942055
02-02 10:01:16.028 32122-10608/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
02-02 10:01:16.028 32122-10608/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling task with Gcm. Time1942055
02-02 10:01:16.038 32122-10608/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 47
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of datareference . Is it null?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of datareference in onCreate method which will be called after onStart method. Inside onStart method, datareference passed will be null.

So initialize the value of datareference in onStart itself.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid populating the RecyclerView inside onStart() method. Its better to call a custom function and implement the code there. For you I will recommend using the code something like this:

```js
 public void populateFeed(){
         FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new 
         FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, BlogViewHolder>(
                    Userstories.class,
                    R.layout.single_post_row,
                    BlogViewHolder.class,
                    dataReference
         )   {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setNameText(model.getName());
                    viewHolder.setProfession(model.getprofession());
                }
            };
    
            recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter); 
       }
```

And at the end of onCreate() dont forget to call the populateFeed() function,

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dataReference = firebase.getReference().child("Users");



        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.story_adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

       populateFeed();
    }
```

This should do the work for you.